# ASP Dropdown list not changing the value

Tags: c#, asp.net

First off, I'm still getting my web dev legs under me. I've combed through piles of SO posts, blogs, newsgroups and articles and I cannot seem to fix my problem. It's very similar to at least 10 different posts I've looked at.

I have an ASP gridview, which acts as a display and a select column. When you click select it throws the data into a detailsview. I have one field that needs to be a drop down box, but whenever I change the value and click update the value that is sent to the command is the original value.

Page Markup:

```
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Planner Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="cboCurrentPlanner" runat="server" DataSourceID="plannerDataSource" 
                        DataTextField="planner_name" DataValueField="planner_id" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("planner_id") %>' AutoPostBack="true" ></asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            </Fields>

            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        </asp:DetailsView>
```

sqlDataSource:

```
            SelectCommand="SELECT vendor_key, vendor, planner_name, street, city, state_country, planner_id, country FROM V_MAP_MarkerInfo WHERE (vendor_key = @vendor_key)" 
            UpdateCommand="MAP_usp_webUpdatePlanToVendor" 
            UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" onupdating="mapDetailSource_Updating" >
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="vendor_key" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="vendor_key" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="planner_id" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name = "vendor" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="plannerDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:vendor_mapConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [planner_id], [planner_name] FROM [MAP_planners]" 
            OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I won't post the stored procedure code, I know that is working. The original value is the only value that makes it to the parameter.

I've tried all sorts of combinations of `<%# Bind/Eval() %>` postbacks but I can't find the right combination.

When I click select, I want the current planner to be selected in the dropdown list. When I select a new planner and click update I would like the planner to update. I'm not sure why this is so difficult or what I have royally screwed up to make it difficult but I am at my wits end. If at all possible, I would like an explanation of what is going on and not just the magical line of code that makes it work.

Flabbergasted is an understatement.

EDITS: `ViewStateEnbabled="true"` added to dropdownlist, the `selectedIndexChanged` event is firing.

EDIT AGAIN: Changed the planner_id to `<asp:ControlParameter>` added monitors to `DetailsView1_OnDataBind` and `MapDataSource1_updating` and the value is all over the place. but I can't see where it's being reset.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `AutoPostBack` property from the dropdown? You might also look into getting rid of the SqlDataSource control, and just bind the data in code-behind.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did do that and I am still not having any luck. I can remove the `SqlDataSource`, I prefer hands on coding over this auto-magic data objects but it's a matter of principle and for my own understanding to get it to work with this method at this point. The rest of the site is coming together quite nice and I am ahead of schedule so I have some time to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am a complete idiot, the `DetailsView DataKeyNames` property was not set correctly. I had accidentally added "planner_id" as a key from the wizard.

The code was fine all along. Thank you to everyone for trying, but I am a lost cause!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `EnableViewState="false"` set on the `@Control` or `@Page` settings? If viewstate is not enabled the control will always have the default value as the selected value. This can be set at the aspx level or the ascx level.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: There was not one in there but I put an `EnableViewState="true"` in and the value is not making it to the parameter.

Comment: If there is not a setting the default is true. What do you mean by it is not getting to the parameter? When the page posts back can you do `cboCurrentPlanner.SelectedValue` and get the value of the dropdown?

Comment: I put a breakpoint in on the `SqlDataSource1_Updating` and in `e.Command` I drilled into the parameter values and it shows the old value. I put in quite a few breaks and I just can't seem to get it working.